# Need to mix an audio signal from a low power device, into a high power speaker

Tags: audio, dsp, mixer

Basically, I want to take a cable going from the car audio amplifier to a speaker which is sending around 50W of power, that cable, and put a mixer in there, where I will inject an audio signal that I want to play with the audio.

I want this device (mixed and audio generator) to be low power, so I need ideas on mixers that dont need to supply the high power current, this is more about the device needs to be made of low cost parts

Here a basic diagram of what I want to do:

[image]

I was thinking about a resistor array, but how do you prevent the power from going in to this box?

Comment: that is like whispering in a hurricane and expecting to be heard

Answer (score 0):

You can't usefully do this. You can't add the low power microphone signal to the cable carrying 50 W from the output of the amplifier to the speaker and expect to hear anything from the microphone. You need to feed the microphone signal and the low power audio input currently going to the amplifier into your mixer and connect the combined signals from the output of the mixer to the input of the audio amplifier.